# Why do Gentoo package maintainers install systemd unit files unconditionally (i.e. without depending on the 'systemd' USE flag)?

Tags: systemd, gentoo

steps to reproduce:

1. issue

   ```
    cd /usr/portage && grep -R "systemd_dounit" *
   ```
2. open several ebuilds and read them

almost all ebuilds use **systemd_dounit** without checking for **systemd** USE-flag first.

Flags are descried here:
https://www.gentoo.org/support/use-flags/
systemd.eclass is described here:
https://devmanual.gentoo.org/eclass-reference/systemd.eclass/index.html

and no, code of function doesn't have checks either:

```
# @FUNCTION: systemd_dounit
# @USAGE: <unit>...
# @DESCRIPTION:
# Install systemd unit(s). Uses doins, thus it is fatal in EAPI 4
# and non-fatal in earlier EAPIs.
systemd_dounit() {
    debug-print-function ${FUNCNAME} "${@}"

    (
        insinto "$(_systemd_get_unitdir)"
        doins "${@}"
    )
}
```

Comment: This behavior is controlled by the `systemd` USE Flag,  The USE Flag controls what init system the system you've built is using.  This flag is also universally set, i.e. inherited using a profile that contains the word `systemd`.  Use `eselect profiles list` to see those available.  Pre EAPI 4 builds did not differentiate between init systems, therefore as a work around, the ebuild installs for both.  This behavior carried over, as Gentoo does not force you to use one init system over the other.

Comment: EAPI=4 contains strange behavior in regards to `doins` and symlinks which is why it's broken.  The split between init systems amd the adoption of separate USE Flags occurred around the time EAPI 5 was adopted.  See [EAPI Usage and Description](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/ebuild-writing/eapi/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Gentoo developer community thinks it's no problem installing those files unconditionally, as long as the systemd dependency is not pulled in. And you can prevent that with `INSTALL_MASK=/usr/lib/systemd` in your `make.conf` (see `man 5 make.conf`).

Comment: This answer more appropriately matches my comments +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IUSE is needed only if you actually reference that USE flag in the ebuild.

In the few ebuilds I checked they don't use the systemd USE flag and just blindly install systemd service definitions in /usr/lib/systemd/system/, just as they blindly install the OpenRC init scripts without checking for the openrc USE flag.

The systemd (and openrc) USE flags are used in ebuilds where the init system makes a material difference, not whether to install a service or init script.

Comment: so, gentoo has a fundamental flaw - it spams my system with unnecessary files, because there is no possibility to reinstall without recompilation?

Comment: More info for your reading displeasure: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Systemd/Ebuild_policy - General guidelines #4. Funtoo discussion: https://bugs.funtoo.org/browse/FL-2091

Comment: @dh3x25bd1f Storage space is essentially free.If installing such files (systemd unit, openrc init, zsh completion, …) unconditionally is a flaw, is merely a matter of personal opinion (and one of the longstanding discussion within the gentoo community). If you don't want systemd files, you can put `INSTALL_MASK=/usr/lib/systemd` in your `make.conf` (see `man 5 make.conf`).